# Non greedy match of .* with ^

Tags: python, regex, placeholder, regex-greedy, non-greedy

Given the string:

```
s = "Why did you foo bar a <b>^f('y')[f('x').get()]^? and ^f('barbar')^</b>"
```

**How do I replace the `^f('y')[f('x').get()]^` and `^f('barbar')^` with a string, e.g. `PLACEXHOLDER`?**

The desired output is:

```
Why did you foo bar a <b>PLACEXHOLDER? and PLACEXHOLDER</b>
```

I've tried `re.sub('\^.*\^', 'PLACEXHOLDER', s)` but the `.*` is greedy and it matches, `^f('y')[f('x').get()]^? and ^f('barbar')^` and outputs:

Why did you foo bar a **PLACEXHOLDER**

There can be multiple substrings of unknown number that's encoded by `\^` so hardcoding this is not desired:

```
re.sub('(\^.+\^).*(\^.*\^)', 'PLACEXHOLDER', s)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a question mark after the star, it will make it non-greedy.

```
\^.*?\^
```

http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97647

```
Why did you foo bar a <b>^f('y')[f('x').get()]^? and ^f('barbar')^</b>
```

Properly replaces to

```
Why did you foo bar a <b>PLACEXHOLDER? and PLACEXHOLDER</b>
```